# Can't SSH to Linux box behind router from Internet

Tags: linux, router, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a Linux box (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS) on my home network that I cannot SSH to from the Internet, through my router. I just get a timeout.

- I have port-forwarding set up on my router
- I can SSH to the box from within my home network
- `/var/log/auth.log` has no entries for external connections
- Verbose flag (`ssh -v`) reveals nothing
- When I re-assign the target of the port-forwarding to be another computer other than the Linux box, for example, a Mac, then I can SSH. This indicates that the port-forwarding configuration works.

Update, output of `/sbin/iptables -n -L -v --line-numbers`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 46 packets, 5731 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 39 packets, 5128 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Use `wireshark` on the Mac to see how a successful connection looks like, compare with `wireshark` on the Linux box to see what goes wrong. Check `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` and `sshd_config` while you are at it.

Comment: Are you using ufw? Check output of 'sudo ufw status' to see if SSH port is allowed. And you are of course having a static IP on your Linux box, that is properly configured in your router?

Comment: Could you add to your question output of `/sbin/iptables -n -L -v --line-numbers` ?

Comment: @Anders ufw is off at the moment

Comment: Firewall then isn't issue since it turned off. Try following: power cycle router and modem; make sure port forwarding is set to correct IP of Ubuntu (it is static IP, right?), try different ports on public side of the router